# Returning counts for unique instances of an aggregate

Tags: r

Apologies for not inserting code fragments, I'm still too junior on this site at this stage so it blocks me from doing so.

Long story short, I have a large dataset of over 60000 entries.

I'm aggregating over a variety of different factors (14 different aggregates, over three different sections of the report each).

I'm doing the aggregates based on mean score.

For example, one sample would be:

```
rurageeth3 <- aggregate(rural$Q8, by=list(Age = rural$Age, Ethnicity= rural$Ethnicity), mean, na.rm=TRUE)

rurageeth3 <- rurageeth3[order(rurageeth3$x, decreasing=T),]

rurageeth3
        Age Ethnicity         x
6    Eleven     Black 10.000000
11  Fifteen     Mixed  9.500000
10   Eleven     Mixed  9.375000
1    Eleven     Asian  9.000000
2  Fourteen     Asian  9.000000
7   Fifteen     Black  9.000000
8  Fourteen     Black  9.000000
16   Eleven     Other  9.000000
17 Fourteen     Other  9.000000
21   Eleven     White  8.978799
26   Twelve     White  8.860465
25 Thirteen     White  8.841026
12 Fourteen     Mixed  8.666667
19 Thirteen     Other  8.666667
24  Sixteen     White  8.644444
23 Fourteen     White  8.623288
5    Twelve     Asian  8.600000
15   Twelve     Mixed  8.583333
22  Fifteen     White  8.576087
9  Thirteen     Black  8.500000
14 Thirteen     Mixed  8.300000
13  Sixteen     Mixed  8.000000
18  Sixteen     Other  8.000000
20   Twelve     Other  8.000000
3   Sixteen     Asian  7.000000
4  Thirteen     Asian  6.000000
```

Now that I have `rurageeth` initialized, I want to know how many, for instance, Fourteen year old mixed race children were included in the sample.

Any idea of how I can see this data, without having to recreate all 72 aggregates from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data has one row per subject, you would need to count the number of rows for each combination of categories. You can do it separately or at the same time you calculate the means.

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(rural$Q8, by=list(Age = rural$Age, Ethnicity= rural$Ethnicity), 
          FUN = function(x) c("Mean"=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), "Count"=sum(!is.na(x))))
```

`sum(!is.na(x))` counts the number of non-missing values. If you want the total number of values, use `length(x)`.

If you're willing to try other options, both `dplyr` and `data.table` are very fast. Here's a `dplyr` example:

```
library(dplyr)

# This will count the number of rows for each combination of Age and Ethnicity
rural %>% group_by(Age, Ethnicity) %>% tally()
```

Comment: Fantastic, all of these options worked excellently.  Thank you so much!